# axios + Vuex - avoid having to catch a reject Promise twice?

Tags: javascript, es6-promise, vuex

I'm using vuex alongside Vue.js + Django. It's my first foray into reactive front-end development.

I'm using a Django REST setup, and wanted to emulate a server error or connection problem, and see how to handle that. So I modified my ViewSet to look like this (**return 0/ or Response 403**). Here's how it looks:

```
class ToDoViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    """
    API endpoint that allows messages to be viewed or edited.
    """
    queryset = ToDoItem.objects.all()
    serializer_class = ToDoItemSerializer
    # return 0 instead of a Response object for testing purposes 
    def destroy(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        instance = self.get_object()
        instance_id = instance.id
        # self.perform_destroy(instance)
        return 0
        # return Response(data={'id': instance_id}, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
```

I'm using **axios to make the `DELETE` call**:
    /// api is mapped to an axios.create object
    deleteToDoItem(ToDoItemId) {
            return api.delete(`todos/${ToDoItemId}`)
                .then(response => response.data)
        }

I have the following **in my vuex store.js**:

```
actions: {
    ....
    deleteToDoItem(context, toDoItemId) {
      messageService.deleteToDoItem(toDoItemId).then(response => context.commit('REMOVE_TODO', response));
    },
```

And the following in **my toDo Vue component**:

```
import { mapActions } from 'vuex';
    export default {
        name: 'todo-item',
        props: ['todo'],
        methods: {
            ...mapActions([
                'deleteToDoItem',
            ]),
            ///  DeleteToDo uses the mapped action 'deleteToDoItem'
            deleteToDo(todo_id) {
                this.deleteToDoItem(todo_id).then(response => this.$store.commit('REMOVE_TODO', response)).catch((e => console.log(e)));
            }
        },

    }
```

I thought the `catch` in DeleteToDo in the component should suffice, but I'm still getting this error:

> Uncaught (in promise) Error: Request failed with status code 500

If I add the following in the axios call:

```
deleteToDoItem(ToDoItemId) {
        return api.delete(`todos/${ToDoItemId}`)
            .then(response => response.data).catch(e => e)
    }
```

Then I don't get the the Uncaught Promise error above, but this seems redundant. Do I have to catch twice? And if I do write it twice, how do I pass the `e` from the axios call down to the action so I can discern what to do?

Comment: I think you will have to call the `.catch()`-block in your vuex store.js. I got a similar situation and solved it by this approach.

Comment: but then I can't properly discern which error happened, how can I pass the original `e` from the axios call to the parent?

Comment: you could return the dispatch-methods directly without any .then(), .catch(), .finally()-block.

Comment: Can you elaborate?

Comment: Remove the then and catch blocks everywhere except in the call of your .vue-file.
In your axios-js file it should look like this: `return api.delete(`todos/${ToDoItemId}`)` . And in your vuex file like this: `return messageService.deleteToDoItem(toDoItemId)`

Comment: I found some additional info according promises [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23803743/what-is-the-explicit-promise-construction-antipattern-and-how-do-i-avoid-it?rq=1).

Comment: @Kodiak your suggestion only resulted in more errors, sadly.